# Manipulate the string data in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data set something like this, B column is character:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B,
  "902640", "2007-12-09 14:52:21.000"
)
```

I want to have it something like this and B column should be the date:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B,
  "902640", "2007-12-09"
)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `gsub("(.*)( )(.*)", "\\1", df$B)`

Comment: How to keep the first column? @AllanCameron

Comment: `df$B <- gsub("(.*)( )(.*)", "\\1", df$B)`. Now `df` will have the correct value